# Inputing strings into an array of strings

Tags: arrays, c

I have this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char arr[10][80];
    int n;
    scanf_s("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        fgets(arr[i],80,stdin);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%s",arr[i]);
}
```

For the most part it works well except for one thing:
It only reads `n-1` strings. So for `n=3`, it will only let me input 2 strings before it prints them and the program ends. Why is this?

Comment: Did you try to run your program in a debugger and step through it? If not, you should do this as very first step. Also you should check return values.

Comment: scanf stops immediately after the int leaving a newline waiting to be read by the first fgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everybody noticed, `scanf_s("%d",&n);` leaves the newline in the input stream so the first `fgets` reads this and stores it in `arr[0]`.

The solution is now not to wildly do some extra reading into undefined memory locations, but to look at the format specifier of `scanf_s`. In particular:

*The format argument specifies the interpretation of the input and can contain one or more of the following:*

- *White-space characters: blank (' '); tab ('\t'); or newline ('\n'). A white-space character causes scanf to read, but not store, all consecutive white-space characters in the input up to the next non–white-space character. One white-space character in the format matches any number (including 0) and combination of white-space characters in the input.*
- ...

So al that is required is to adapt the format specifier into `scanf_s("%d ",&n);` in whch only a space is added, which tells `scanf` to read up to and including the newline character. QED.

Comment: yup this is certently better then my solution, gj!